# How to specify matching patterns while excluding some files having a PATTERN in their filenames

Tags: grep

**NOTE**: I have updated this question from what I posted earlier and hence some answers may not match with what I intend to ask.

I want to search some TEXT in a set of files in sub-directories and simultaneously want to skip results from certain files having "svn" in their filenames.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: You may find [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/) useful. It is a programmer friendly `grep` that understands many versioning systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The details will depend on what exactly you want to do, but [negative lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) might help. Certain regular expression languages, including PCRE support this. You can activate PCREs in `grep` with the `-P` switch, so depending on the specific pattern you are looking for, you might be able to do something clever with these but it is very unlikely to be worth the effort.

Having read your update however, there are much better ways of doing it. `grep` offers the `-exclude` option:

```
   --exclude=GLOB
          Skip  files  whose  base  name  matches  GLOB  (using   wildcard
          matching).   A  file-name  glob  can  use  *,  ?,  and [...]  as
          wildcards, and \ to quote  a  wildcard  or  backslash  character
          literally.
```

So, you could simply do

```
grep -Inr TEXT --exclude='*.svn' dir/
```

Comment: The only problem with using lookarounds is that look-behinds need to be a fixed length, so they can't be used to do anything generically.

Comment: @Graeme I know, it's trivial if the string to be avoided is adjacent to the pattern but gets complicated otherwise. That's why I didn't give an example, not really worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do both a positive search (`grep`) and a negative search (`grep -v`). Alternative would be to use `-E` (or `egrep`, which is same thing) and provide a matching regular expression that would match one string but not match the other.

Comment: That will simply ignore _both_ strings.

Comment: Yeah that was a bad call, I have updated it to provide a more generic answer

Comment: Better :) Still, the -E is not needed, you can provide a regular expression to normal grep. `-E` just uses ERE instead of BRE.

Comment: @MadHatter that's grep's default behavior. It always expects a regular expression as a search string. `-E` (like `-P`) simply change the regex language used.

Answer (score 0):

In case you discover that you need more sophisticated control of the files you are grepping than is offered by `--exclude`, you can use `find` to produce the list of files for grep:

`$ grep 'whatever_you_want_to_find' $(find wherever_you_want_to_search -not -iregex 'whatever_you_want_to_ignore')`